As an indie game developer who sells game in Steam, can someone overseas sue me because they know i won't be there to defend myself in court?
I'm planning to sell a game in Steam (the game is still in development), i'm currently an indie game developer working alone. There is one legal issues that i haven't yet find the answer regarding jurisdiction of game purchases through internet.
Suppose i release my game in Steam and many people buy it, and suppose i post social media link where user can interact with each other such as discord/facebook/twitter etc, and suppose i post business email so that people who want to do business regarding my game can contact me.
Does that means my game in Steam have "minimum contacts" which made it eligible to be sued from practically any court in the world? If yes, does that means any big game companies who want to stifle competition can just sue me from 100+ countries and get my game banned everywhere because i can't practically defense myself in court? to think about it, if the answer to all of that is yes, that means anyone can drag me to court for my game if i randomly decide to visit a country for a vacation.

I would assume that this is part of why basically every EULA has language like "if you decide to sue me, you agree to do so in the court of X jurisdiction".

@nick012000 That would, of course, still have to be enforced somehow in other (foreign) courts, and it's unlikely the one filing the suit is going to conveniently point out that they agreed to be in a different court. So you still need to hire representation locally so they can argue to the court that this should be in a different court.

Of course they can sue you, with or without a good reason. And if you are not represented in court you might lose a civil case without doing anything wrong.
In a civil case that person would have a problem to make you pay. For example, a UK court can’t force you to pay me £100 if you are in the USA.
And lying in court to win a case is often a serious crime. If I lie in a UK court so you lose a civil case, you could tell UK police for several years and I could get into real trouble. US police would likely not act because the crime (making false statements in court) happened outside the USA.

If you do something that harms someone, they can sue you
If that harm takes place in a foreign country, they can sue you in that country.
This has nothing in particular to do with games or software but is just the way things are for everything. If you choose to operate in a foreign country, you potentially expose yourself to liability in that country. And, if you don’t comply with that country’s law, you expose yourself to prosecution.
You don’t need to be there to defend yourself
That’s what lawyers are for - you hire one where you get sued and they defend you.
